# jQuery ui accordion with panel that contains scrolling content and a fixed header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I would like to have an accordion with a panel that has a fixed header with a date picker in it and scrollable content while the accordion has fillspace set to true. So the accordion panel called panel-hmmm should not scroll but the div inside called scrollable-content should.

```
<div id="accordion-west">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">hmmm</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="panel-hmmm">
        <div class="date-picker">
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-content">
            <b>Accordion inside a layout-pane</b>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum
                neque a velit laoreet dapibus. Etiam eleifend tempus pharetra.</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
            <p>
                .</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">chips</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">
            Sed Non Urna</p>
        <p>
            Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit,
            dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus
            libero ac justo.</p>
        <p>
            Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.panel-hmmm .date-picker').datepicker();
        $("#accordion-west").accordion({
            fillSpace: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want exactly, but try adding this CSS. Adjust the height to fit inside the area you want it.

```
.panel-hmmm {
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 300px;
}
```

Replace `.panel-hmmm` with `.ui-accordion-content` to effect all of the accordion panels.

---

Update: Given that you want the datepicker always visible when the panel is open, I'd switch the CSS to:

```
.scrollable-content {
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 300px;
}
```

The height of this scrollable content needs to be set otherwise it will maintain it's full height. In a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NtWUp/) I set up, the accordion panel would go off the page without any CSS, which is why I initially set the `.panel-hmmm` to a vertain height.

Comment: i am after a datepicker which is always visible and a scrolling panel underneath it all within a panel in the accordion.
panel-hmmm needs to be an unfixed height so it can fill the space the accordion is contained in. So when the window size changes so does the height of the accordion and therefore the panel. Adding this css fixes the height of the div which contains both the datepicker and scrollable-content. i just want the scollable-content div to scroll

Comment: I've updated my answer above. Hopefully this will be more along the lines of what you want. :)

Comment: ok, that is cool. all i need now i think is to make the scrollable-content height fill the space in the .panel-hmmm dynamically. The height of .scrollable-content = height of .panel-hmmm - height of .date-picker.

I would love to apply that formula but the accordion does not have a resize event, right? Any ideas?